# Android JSON Parsing URL

Tags: php, android, json, url

I'm new to StackOverflow and Android altogether. I successfully parsed JSON from a direct URL

```
http://jsonapptest.x10host.com/index.php
```

The problem I'm facing is I'm trying to make everything a little more complex by adding PHP's URL ?= function.
So, on a normal browser loading up :

```
http://jsonapptest.x10host.com/index.php?page=
```

works fine.
In my App; it doesn't work at all (blank white screen)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
// Log tag
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// Movies json url
private static final String url = "http://jsonapptest.x10host.com/index.php?page=";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
```

Please give me a hand, I'm confused.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my index.php file. I had `<HTML>` and `<body>` tags. I removed all tags except for my `<?php` and it loads up fine.